# HTML Picture Re-size and Centering

Tags: html, image, resize

I've read though many of the posts trying to re size my image but its not working, can someone help me out with centering and making the image smaller?

HTML:

```
<div id="mainBody">
<div id="image">
    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/6b22cnbfd/jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainBody{
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;}
.image {
    width: 60%;
    position: fixed;
    align-items: center;}
.image img{
    position: fixed;
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;}
'
```

Comment: Could it be because you're using id attributes in your HTML and you're styling classes in CSS ?

Comment: .mainBody -> the '.' means a class but you are using it in your html as id not class.. you should use '#' instead for id. (ex. #mainBody) this is applicable to the others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not centering because it's position is set to fixed. `margin: 0 auto` will not work for fixed position elements. You'd have to set the `left` to 50% and then have a negative `margin-left` pull it back half of the width. For example:

```
img {
    position:fixed;
    width:300px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e24d0bx6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your css refers to .image img when its the id that's image, 
so should be #image img

and you want to specify a with attribute:
maybe max-width:80%
or width: 400px

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use position or margin but it may not work if you have many image with different size.
The better way, I think you should use background-image. Like this:

Html

```
<div id="image">
</div>
```

Css

```
#image {
    background-image: url(path/to/your/image);
    background-position: center;
    //set size of #image div like you want
}
```